# possible bot or broken ipv6 slowing connection speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping, ipv6

I have a relatively new netgear c7800 cable modem wifi router connected to 23 various items ranging from wall switches, echos, phones, tablet, and computers.

My computer is a Windows 10 lenovo (2 years old). Comcast has been sending a pop up that i have a bot. I pinged google and it times out. Web pages load slowly with about 15 seconds latency to connect. I had a technician come out from comcast. We checked my wife's computer, the ping works with one timeout. If i unplug my computer from network speed tests and pings are perfect on wife's computer. So, my computer is affecting network. If i disable ipv6, mine works fine. He checked everything else and said their stuff is fine, it is my computer.

I sat with McAfee remoting into my computer for 4 hours, he said he ran everything he could. it is clean. I ran rootkit from malwarebytes and McAfee. The problem is still present. I tried looking at the network usage in the settings window. I googled each, they look legit and the usage does not seem enough to affect the speed test for what i am seeing.

Can someone guide me what else to look for?

edit: I have both mcafee and malware bytes installed. Ran fine up til a few weeks ago. If i disable malware bytes, ping connects and web pages load instantly. Maybe one of their updates changed something.I opened a ticket with them and will update this once i get an answer from them.

Comment: Compare `ping -4 www.google.com` vs `ping -6`. Similarly compare `tracert`. Check what IPv4 and v6 DNS servers you have in `ipconfig /all`.

Comment: Ok, dumb/scary question - do you know its really McAfee? There's a ton of tech support scams going on.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Unless my entire internet is rerouted, i should be okay, i turned off ipv6 to make it fast, then i went straight to McAfee web site and logged into my account and initiated a chat to technical support.